# How to remove tab page using a string variable

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I have a tab id in a string:

```
string tab_name = "tabPage1";
```

The tab id comes from an sql db, so it's not fixed as above. How to remove it at the program start?
This is most likely incorrect:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_name);
```

Comment: Yes because this method takes `TabPage` as a parameter, not `string`.

Comment: But if you check `TabPageCollection` you'll see a nice method called `RemoveByKey`...(btw I wouldn't tie in that way control name with DB value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `Name` property to each `TabPage`:

```
tabControl1.TabPages[0].Name = "tabPage1";
// ...
```

Remove `TabPage` later by it's `Name`:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey("tabPage1");
```

Comment: Well, the names have been set by default to be tabPage1, tabPage2, etc. Thanks a lot.